# Realm Object Server - How to get the server Admin Access Token?

Tags: realm-mobile-platform

I have installed ROS on to Ubuntu.  Unfortunately the document I thought I had saved the Admin Access Token into is blank!  :(

Does anyone know how to get this token value again?  Or re-gererate it?

Answer (score 2):

And in the documentation......

```
cat /etc/realm/admin_token.base64
```

Comment: @RonakChaniyara - Your comment does not make sense.  The answer I posted is the answer to my question.